# jquery.js not loading in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, manifest, reload

When using a website with just 'jquery.js' (actually jQuery1.10.2.js) statically loaded (see below) with a manifest, the page issues an error by inspect element => console:

http://misc.nicejewel.com/jquery.png

The first time I load the page it is OK but all subsequent loads (cmd+R reload) issue this error. Altering the URL by adding a dummy parameter loads the page correctly (presumably no cache) and subsequent reloads with the same URL issue the same error.

The problem can be reproduced on:

- Chrome 31 on OSX and Android
- Opera 15 on Android (same Webkit)

Other browsers (Firefox, Safari) don't have this problem.

What is wrong with the manifest ?

Here the contents of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="startpage.manifest">
<head>
<title>Startpagina</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

</head><body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added `jquery.js` in your cache manifest. If you add cache manifest to a page it will update only if the cache file itself is modified, if it's not modified it will try to load everything from the cache.